# riloadr.js only showing mobile image for Ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad, mobile, responsive-design

I have the following code:

```
// Responsive image loading (riloadr)
var riloadrDefaultGroup = new Riloadr({
    breakpoints: [
        {name: 'mobile', maxWidth: 699},
        {name: 'tablet', minWidth: 700, maxWidth: 959},
        {name: 'desktop', minWidth: 960}
    ],
    watchViewportWidth: '*'
});
```

If I'm on desktop and resize my browser, everything works correctly. Image src's swap out while resizing, and only one of the 3 images loads on refresh.

What is happening with iPad that it only cares for the `maxWidth: 699` breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

[riloadr.js](https://github.com/tubalmartin/riloadr) uses window.screen.width in conjunction with the device's DPI. On an iPad, this returns `384px` (768px / 2dpi)

Use the following:

```
// Responsive image loading (riloadr)
var riloadrDefaultGroup = new Riloadr({
    breakpoints: [
        {name: 'mobile', maxWidth: 699},
        // use the original (or "base") tablet values divided by the dpi for tablet
        {name: 'tablet', minWidth: 350, maxWidth: 480, minDevicePixelRatio: 2}, // retina portrait
        {name: 'tablet', minWidth: 700, maxWidth: 959}, // these are the base numbers as they might appear on a desktop browser
        // use the original (or "base") desktop values divided by the dpi for desktop
        {name: 'desktop', minWidth: 480, minDevicePixelRatio: 2}, //retina landscape
        {name: 'desktop', minWidth: 960},  // these are the base numbers as they might appear on a desktop browser
    ],
    watchViewportWidth: '*'
});
```

If there's a 3dpi device, divide your tablet/desktop (as they might appear on a desktop computer with a dpi of 1) by 3...

`{name: 'desktop', minWidth: 320, minDevicePixelRatio: 3}`